# $2$ circles internally tangent to a third one with given values of radii and length of 2 chords. Find the value of a certain product of lengths

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

The line AB goes through P. The radius of the red circle is 81, the large black circle is 99, and the blue circle 18. The line XY is tangent to the red and blue circles.

Find NX*NA.[image: The diagram]

I made an attempt via finding many side lengths (Found that the distance between O_2 and X is 54, and that ABN and YXN are similar. However, this didn't lead to anywhere. I also found the ratio between AX and XN is 9/2.
I've also found that sin(ANB) is 2/3.

Comment: To clarify: PB has length 24, AP has length 108, AB has length 132, Y-O2 has length 18

Comment: How did you find out $AB = 132$? With just the given radii of the three circles, $AB$ is not fixed.

Comment: @MathLover O2 is supposed to be on the red circle.

Comment: Yes I see now. Your diagram confused me a bit. One of the ways is to use extended Sine law to find $AX$.

Comment: @MathLover I made a better diagram in GeoGebra, with only the information given in the problem.

Comment: Using the similarity of triangles, $NX/BN=NY/NA \iff NX.NA=BN.NY$ which mean that the power of $N$ with respect to the red circle (the quantity that has to be found) must be equal to the power of $N$ with respect to the small (black) circle, therefore $N$ belongs to the radical axis of the red and the small circle. But after...

Comment: @JeanMarie I was thinking Power of A Point as well, however, I don't believe there are enough right angles to use it.

Comment: This question definitely is possible, as none of the circles can "move around" while still keeping everything tangent.

Comment: You are not a new user, so why do you avoid 
[MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?
Are you waiting for somebody to do it for you?

Comment: The question is understandable without MathJax. Since the OP has already spent so much time on their diagram, if you have any improvements you can make them yourself.

Comment: Same question as Math lover. How did you find AB=132 (and AP=108) ?

Comment: On the graphics, tracing OA  and OB would be helpful...

Comment: Be so kind as to explain in your text **the order in which the points and the circles are constructed** + the data you have right at the beginning ($PB =24, AP=108, AB =132$). A good way to do that would be to give a link to your (very nice) Geogebra construction.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of modifying your title which was not informative ("geometry problem with chords")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Edit: Adding a solution using similarity of triangles and Pythagoras theorem**

$\small O_2X^2 = XT^2 + O_2T^2 = XT^2 +  O_1O_2^2 - (O_1X - XT)^2= 18^2 + 81^2 - 63^2$

$\implies \small O_2X = 54$.

As $O_1O = O_2P = 18, O_1P = OO_2 = 81, $ then we must have $ \small \ O_1P \parallel OB$.

Now you can show $ \small \angle AO_1P = \angle OO_1O_2$.

If $\small AU \perp O_1P \text { and } O_2W \perp AO, \triangle O_1 O_2 W \cong \triangle O_1 A U$.

$\small AU^2 = AO_1^2 - O_1U^2 = 81^2 - 9^2, AP^2 = AU^2 + PU^2 = 81^2 - 9^2 + (81-9)^2$

$ \displaystyle \small AU = 36 \sqrt{5}, AP = 108, AV = \frac{11}{9} AU = 44 \sqrt5, OV = 11$

$\small AO_2^2 = AV^2 + VO_2^2 \implies AO_2 = 54 \sqrt5$

Now note that $ \displaystyle \small \angle O_2AX = \frac{1}{2} \angle O_2O_1X \implies \triangle O_2AS \sim \triangle O_2O_1M$

That leads to $ \small O_2S = 18 \sqrt5$ and applying Pythagoras theorem gives you $\small AS$ and $\small SX$. Adding them,

$\small AX = 36 (\sqrt{10}+1)$

As $ \small \ O_1P \parallel OB, \angle AXP = \angle ANB \implies PX \parallel BN$

$ \therefore \displaystyle \small \frac{AN}{AX} = \frac{AB}{AP} = \frac{OB}{O_1P} = \frac{99}{81} = \frac{11}{9} \implies 
AN = \frac{11}{9} \cdot AX, XN = \frac{2}{9} \cdot AX$

$ \displaystyle \small NX \cdot NA = \frac{2}{9} \cdot \frac{11}{9} \cdot AX^2 = 352 (11 + 2 \sqrt{10})$

**Solution using trigonometry:**

For calculation of $ \small AP$ and $ \small O_2X$ and establishing $ \small PX \parallel BN$, please see previous solution.

If $ \displaystyle \small \angle PAO_2 = \alpha$, $\sin \alpha = \sin (\frac{1}{2} \angle PO_1O_2) = \frac{9}{81} = \frac{1}{9}$

If $ \displaystyle \small \angle O_2 A X = \beta$, $\sin \beta = \sin (\frac{1}{2} \angle O_2 O_1 X) = \frac{27}{81} = \frac{1}{3}$

If $ \small \angle AXP = \gamma \text { and } R \text { is circumradius of } \triangle APX, R = 81$.

$ \displaystyle \small 2R \sin \gamma = AP \implies \sin \gamma = \frac{2}{3}$

$ \small AX = 2 R \sin \angle APX = 2 R \sin (180^0 - (\alpha + \beta) - \gamma) \small = 162 \sin (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)$

$ \displaystyle \small \sin (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{4\sqrt5}{9} = \frac{4\sqrt5+2\sqrt2}{27}$

$ \displaystyle \small \cos(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{8\sqrt{10}-1}{27}, \cos \gamma = \frac{\sqrt5}{3}$

$ \displaystyle \small \sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) = \frac{2 (\sqrt{10}+1)}{9}$

So $ \small AX = 36 (\sqrt{10}+1)$

From here, follow the same steps as in previous solution.

Comment: Remarkable!....

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you. I added a solution without trigonometry but the diagram has become too cluttered. Will have to make a fresh diagram and add later.

Comment: Is the fact that $O_1P \parallel OB$ part of the hypotheses ?

Comment: @JeanMarie as $O_2$ is on the red circle, points $O, O_2, B$ must be collinear and so $OO_2 = 81$ and $O_1P = 81$. Similarly points $O, O_1, A$ must be collinear so $OO_1 = 18$ and $O_2P = 18$. So quadrilateral $OO_1PO_2$ must be a parallelogram.

Comment: Evident! Thank you.